# How to handle duplicate note_on, note_off, tempo change in more than one tracks, and tracks without program_change in a midi file?

Tags: midi, mido

I'm using `Mido` for python, working on parsing midi files into `<start_time, duration, program, pitch>` tuples and met some problems.

Some files that I parse has multiple `note_on`, resulting in notes at the same pitch and same program being opened more than once.

Some files contains multiple `note_off` resulting in trying to close notes that is no longer on due to being closed before (assuming only one note at the same program and same pitch can be on).

Some tracks does not have a `program_change` in the beginning of the track (or even worse, not even having one in the whole track).

Some files has more than one track containing `set_tempo` messages.

What should I do in each of these cases to ensure I get the correct interpretation?

Comment: For MIDI devices, tracks do not matter. Are these commands on the same channel?

Comment: @CL. Yes, same channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to get a correct MIDI message stream, you have to merge all tracks in a type 1 file. What matters for a synthesizer are not tracks, but channels.

The MIDI specification says:

> **ASSIGNMENT OF NOTE ON/OFF COMMANDS**
>
> If an instrument receives two or more Note On messages with the same key number and MIDI channel, it must make a determination of how to handle the additional Note Ons. It is up to the receiver as to whether the same voice or another voice will be sounded, or if the messages will be ignored. The transmitter, however, must send a corresponding Note Off message for every Note On sent. If the transmitter were to send only one Note Off message, and if the receiver in fact assigned the two Note On messages to different voices, then one note would linger. Since there is no harm or negative side effect in sending redundant Note Off messages this is the recommended practice.

---

The General MIDI System Level 1 Developer Guidelines say that in response to a “GM System On” message, a device should set Program Change to 0. So you can assume this to be the initial value for channels that have notes without a preceding Program Change.

---

The Standard MIDI Files specification says that

> tempo information should always be stored in the first MTrk chunk.

But "should" is not "must".

Comment: So is it that, I make the final decision on the parsing results? Also, do you have any idea on channels without a default program?